# How to change dataset name when running test in PHPUnit? (using DataProvider)

Tags: php, laravel, testing, phpunit

Is there a way to rename DataProvider dataset at runtime (when test is running)?

I have a Trait that has DataProvider that generates datasets dynamically. But I cant give them descriptive names when DataProvider method is run because I expect different result depending on particular TestCase wgich uses this Trait, and I cant figure out what result I expect because my setUp method hasnt been invoked yet.

My particular example: I have a trait that checks if page is accessible with various combinations of user permissions. And all I can see in my report now is

```
check access with dataset "permissions: allow_this"
check access with dataset "permissions: allow_this, allow_that"
```

I'd like to see more descriptive names like

```
check access with dataset "deny when permissions: allow_this"
check access with dataset "allow when permissions: allow_this, allow_that"
```

But to figure out whether I should allow the user to access this page I have to check some data in my DB, but I can do it only later in my setUp method that hasnt been invoked yet..

Yes, I already know expected result after setUp has been called, but seems like I cant rename dataset at this time already... or maybe I can?

**Upd 4 @mrhn:**
The example that demonstrates inability of giving descriptive name at dataProvider runtime:

```
class VehiclesEditPageTest extends TestCase
{
    use BasicResponseTestWithAuth;

    public function setUp():void {
        parent::setUp();

        $vehicle = Vehicle::create([
            'number' => 'x000xx00',
        ]);
        $this
            ->setBasicResponseTestPageUrl(route('admin.dataobjects.vehicles.edit', $vehicle->id))
            ->setBasicResponseTestRequiredPermissions(['can_access_admin_zone', 'can_access_dataobjects_zone']);
    }
}
```

and a part of Trait:

```
trait BasicResponseTestWithAuth {
    use RefreshDatabase;

    private $basicResponseTestPageUrl;
    private $basicResponseTestRequiredPermissions = ['--no--access--'];  // no access by default
    private $basicResponseTestAuthorizedRedirectsToUrl;

    // ...

    public function test_access($shouldAccess, $permissions) {
        // have to figure it out here, not in dataProvider method
        $shouldAccess = $this->basicResponseTestShouldAccess($permissions);

        $user_role = UserRole::factory()->create($permissions);
        $user = User::factory()->create([
            'user_role_id' => $user_role->id,
        ]);
        $this->actingAs($user);

        $response = $this->get($this->basicResponseTestPageUrl);

        if(!$shouldAccess) {
            $response->assertStatus(403);
        } else {
            $response->assertStatus(200);
        }
    }

    // ...

    public function provide_access_data() {
        $data = array_map(
            function ($permissions) {
                return [
                    $this->basicResponseTestShouldAccess($permissions), // <-- it doesnt work properly here, so we recall it later in TEST method
                    $permissions
                ];
            },
            $this->getAllPermissionsCombinations()
        );
        $data_named = array_combine(
            // ...therefore here we have all tests named as "deny for ...."
            array_map(fn($data) => ($data[0] ? 'allow for   ' : 'deny for   ') . implode(' + ', array_keys(array_filter($data[1]))), $data),
            $data
        );
        return $data_named;
    }

}
```

as you can see I have to create a Vehicle object in my DB in order to test Vehicle Edit page response.

I coulde've made all other setup stuff out of setUp method (e.g. use private methods for setting page url and required permissions) but I cant do any DB stuff such early in Test lifecycle AFAIK.

I thought about setting only route names and model's classes here (using class methods) and creating models in trait's Test method, but it doesnt seem like one-stop and reusable solution, because some other pages could require smth different to be created then just one model to test it's accessibility.

**Upd2:**

today after taking a look on thit post I've come up with idea to separate initialization (to setup permissions in properties to make them accessible in dataProvider to calculate expected result, and then setup page url in setUp method when DB connection is ready to use).

Doesnt seem very elegant, though should work, as far as I can assume.

Comment: You can't, dataproviders are run before setUp, that is why you do not have Laravel available inside them

Comment: @matiaslauriti but is it really impossible to change the name later? maybe not the name itself but just that one that is displayed in the report?

Comment: Yes, it is impossible. I did also struggle with this, and yes, you cannot change it later, because once you are running something from the test class that is not the dataprovider, it means the test is already running and it already has the dataprovider descriptive name on it, just waiting the result. You could modifiy the dataprovider on the test to iterate over the stuff you want to put in the dataprovider, at that moment you can put any name. Create a method that returns an array with permissions, and if you can know which one is which, then you can change the index name and return an array

Comment: @matiaslauriti okay, thanx for this. Seems I have to reorganize all my tests to achieve what I want

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact problem recently, but it was mostly how the `PHPStorm` test runner changed the output.

Through this i found out you could use the array structure for the `dataprovider()` to actually tweak the name. By using the key for naming purpose, which will not change the execution of the tests.

If you apply that idea to the dataprovider.

```
function dataProvider() {
    return [
        'deny when permissions' => ['permissions: allow_this'],´
    ];
}
```

You would get the following result based on how `PHPUnit` by default transform the data. Which i assume will suffice.

```
check access with dataset with data set "deny when permissions" ('permissions: allow_this, allow_that')
```

Comment: Saw there was something with loading data after the setup of the testclasses, after i answered. i could not totally understand, letting the answer stand if it can help you, if it's off the mark lets delete it to not confuse people looking for help on this later :)

Comment: yep, I know that the assoc key is considered as the test name, but the issue is that I can't give a name at DataProvider method runtime, because I have to make some setup first (it's because all this logic is placed into Trait and the particular expected result depends on setup actions made in setUp method of each particular class uses this trait)

Comment: can you include an example of what you are actually setting up, could be there was another way around it?

Comment: yep, check out the update in the topic.